# Unable to set property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net, properties, innertext

I have wrote this code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

    function btnClient_onclick() {
        document.getElementById("lblClient").innerText = "Changed";
        document.getElementById("lblServer").innerText = "Server";

    }

// ]]>
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Welcome to ASP.NET!
</h2>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnServer" runat="server" onclick="btnServer_Click" 
        Text="Server" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblServer" runat="server" Text="Server"></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="btnClient" type="button" value="Client" onclick="return btnClient_onclick()" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblClient" runat="server" Text="Client"></asp:Label>
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

and when i run it, got this errro : Unable to set property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference

Comment: That means `getElementById` is not finding an element with the specified ID.

Comment: I don't know ASP.Net, but I'll bet it's because you have `runat="server"`, so the label isn't available on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Set

> ClientIDMode to static

on both the labels and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById("lblClient").setAttribute('text', "Changed");
```